# Typescript: get the ID of the 'parent' after a drop event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop

I am using DevExpress and Angular 10. I would like to drag a person into an appointment. It works if I drag it beneath the

tags. If I drag an item into to appointment but on the p html tags, I don't know how to get the ID of the appointment.

the html:

As you see, the yellow part is the wanted ID.
[image]

As mentioned before, if I drop the item beneath the p tags: [image]

(the red spot), I can get the ID. Otherwise I don't.

the app.component.ts:

```
e.addEventListener('drop', event => {
  let appointmentId = parseInt(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id.split('--')[0]);
}
```

I already tried working with event.target.parentElement or event.srcElement.offSetparent but nothing works in both situations. How can I make sure that the drop event sees the appointment as the 'head/main' one to get the ID?

Kind regards

Comment: I would set a breakpoint inside the listener, and then explore the whole event object and check if there is the desired id.

Comment: Yes the desired id is there if a drag into the red spot via ```let appointmentId = parseInt(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id.split('--')[0]); ```  But if I drag into the text of the appointment, I cannot get the ID the same way. I'm searching for a way to set the div I want as 'main' element to take the ID of in a drop event. Regardless of the other elements that are inside the div..